# Using contentWindow.postMessage to control YouTube videos embedded in iframe--where can I find a list of "func"?

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, postmessage

I'm new to front-end development so maybe this is a stupid question.
I'm trying to write a program to control YouTube videos embedded using vanilla JavaScript.
I found an example in this [Control YouTube video with vanilla javascript](https://codepen.io/renduh/pen/ELBRYj) link.
I noticed the author uses **contentWindow.postMessage()** to send the command to the iframe.

For example, to play the YouTube video, the code is something like

```html
div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
```

Where can I find a complete list of "func" (e.g. "playVideo")? I googled using keywords like "postMessage", "iframe", "playVideo", etc but couldn't find any documentation that answers my question.

I want to be able to control the YouTube video more precisely. In addition to playing/pausing the video, I want to be able to skip to a certain timestamp, control the volume, or even output only the left or right sound channel.

Comment: I did check YouTube's IFrame Player API documentation ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference ), but I don't think it has an answer to my question.

Comment: I found more examples in https://memo.ag2works.tokyo/post-1283/ (sorry it's in Japanese, but the code should be self-explanatory), but still I cannot find a complete list.